# How to keep keyboard focus on textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Throughout the app I need to use ENTER to advance to next control (same as Tab), and I do that by using EventManager.RegisterClassHandler, KeyDownEvent for textboxes in Application_Startup. But for one particular textbox (which is the input for a barcode scanner), I want to keep the focus to allow multiple scannings. So it has to receive a number, process it, then clear the box and keep the focus for the next read. Barcode reader is automatically sending an ENTER at the end of a read. Textbox must still be able to lose focus by user's choice (like mouse clicking in another box)

Comment: You don't.  Just hook into keyboard events directly through the [TextCompositionManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.textcompositionmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  You can watch the keys as they come across and fire off a custom event when an input matches the barcode reader's output.  If you want to dress it up in MVVM, expose an ICommand property on the Window to which you bind your view model, and fire that command off on a scan instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly handle the `PreviewKeyDown` on that box and set `Handled` to `true` on the event arguments. It executes before any `KeyDown` handlers.

Comment: I just tried, it looks like the class handler is executed first, but is a good idea to look into, maybe I'll find some workaround...Thanks

Comment: You can always use `PreviewKeyDown` to prevent the `KeyDown`.

Comment: YES! That was it. Thanks!